# adjust height of parent div plus "same level" div to height of one of the nested divs

Tags: html, css, nested, height, parent-child

I have a responsive design with a div called A, containing two nested divs B and C, who lay next to each other. see url www.tripleconcept.nl/nested_div_height.jpg

Div B contains text (height variable, depending on lenght of text and of width of DIV). In smaller screen sizes the width will be smaller and height longer)
DIV C contains an image.

I would like the lenghth of the text of DIV B to be leading for its height and for the height of containing parent A.
The height of DIV C must adjust also to the height of B and A, which means the width of the image will be cropped.

I cannot figure it out. Who would like to help me write the right css?
thanx!

Comment: can you make jsfiddle??

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly this should help.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92z6s88o/4/)

This is just an example and as you can see it worked for me. 
The trick is `display:table-cell;` in both columns.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Greenz,
thanx for your quick reply...
Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. I have to set the right code for the height, not the width. Width works fine.
Div B has text and it height adjusts upon the length of the text (ánd the smaller the div (in small screens, the larger the height.)
The height of DIV C has to be exactely the same height as B. If the image is too wide, it has to be cropped.... ;-)

Comment: @HedyDezigner I would like to point out that the jsfiddle link that I posted above implements every aspect that you mentioned in your comment. The height of div A and div C are both dependant on how much text is in div B and both have the exact same height as div B. The image is also "cropped" if it is too wide. If you want to see the height of div A you can remove the background color from div B and you will see that div A (blue) extends to the bottom of div B. If your question still hasn't been answered please try to express the problem again. Cheers!